# Are there any methods that combine mcmc and VI?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, variational-inference

Are there any methods that combine VI and MCMC? If it exists, why isn’t it used prominently over techniques such as NUTS or other VIs.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?

Comment: The idea behind VI is to find a tractable variational posterior to approximate the "true" posterior. Once you have this tractable approximation, what would you need sampling for?

Comment: I am trying to understand if it’s able to combine each strength into one. Mcmc is slower compared to vi but asymptotically precise. Vi is faster, less computationally expensive but less accurate.

Comment: Sometimes VI requires additional simulation and MCMC is a potential tool for that purpose.